# Exception while calling json parse

Tags: javascript

I'm getting error like this "Object required: '[string: ""]'" while call this function. Can you please someone help me on this.

```
<script language= "javascript" runat= "server">
Array.prototype.get = function(x) { return this[x]; }; 
function parseJSON(strJSON) { 
    try {
        if(strJSON === "") return""; 
        return eval("(" + strJSON + ")"); 
    } catch(e){ 
        return "";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: which part of the code is vbscript? all I see is javascript

Comment: Would suppose JSON.parse(strJSON) not eval ??

Comment: set jSONResponse = parseJSON(exchangeeSSOTokenAndGetProfileInfo(URL, body)) This is the vbscript code, here i'm calling parseJSON jscript function after that i'm getting "Object required: '[string: ""]' in browser seems like i need to set object can suggest vbscript object to call the parseJSON jscript function.